# Buliding llvm examples, /llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:53: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'

Tags: c++11, compilation, llvm

I'm attempting to follow the steps on http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html to build the example.

based on

[Building llvm examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149118/building-llvm-examples)

[#error "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965870/error-must-define-stdc-limit-macros-before-including-support-datatypes-h)

[Why am I getting "undefined reference to `dladdr'" even with -ldl for this simple program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993460/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-dladdr-even-with-ldl-for-this-simpl)

I've ended up with the command

```
clang++ -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -std=c++11 -g -O3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --libs core --cppflags --ldflags` -o toy
```

which is giving

```
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::MutexImpl(bool)':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:53: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:59: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:67: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Mutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::MutexImpl::tryacquire()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Mutex.cpp:109: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::RWMutexImpl()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:59: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::~RWMutexImpl()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:72: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::reader_acquire()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:82: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::reader_release()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:92: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::writer_acquire()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:102: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(RWMutex.o): In function `llvm::sys::RWMutexImpl::writer_release()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/RWMutex.cpp:112: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function `llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(_IO_FILE*)':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:278: undefined reference to `dladdr'
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Unix/Signals.inc:290: undefined reference to `dladdr'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::ThreadLocalImpl()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/ThreadLocal.cpp:56: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::~ThreadLocalImpl()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/ThreadLocal.cpp:63: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::setInstance(void const*)':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/ThreadLocal.cpp:70: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(ThreadLocal.o): In function `llvm::sys::ThreadLocalImpl::getInstance()':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/ThreadLocal.cpp:77: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/local/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Threading.o): In function `llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread(void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned int)':
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Threading.cpp:91: undefined reference to `pthread_attr_setstacksize'
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Threading.cpp:96: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/abdev/llvmHome/llvm/lib/Support/Threading.cpp:100: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I missing a library, or is some of the order incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to link with -lpthread or just -pthread

Comment: For reference the working command I ended up with

clang++ -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -g -O3 NAME_OF_SOURCE.cpp -o DESIRED_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME -std=c++11 -pthread `llvm-config --libs core` `llvm-config  --cppflags --ldflags` -ldl